# Getting the IP address of a received message in boost

Tags: c++, boost-asio

How can I retrieve the IP address with boost when I receive a UDP message(using boost::asio::ip::udp)?

Thanks!

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How would you put this question?

Comment: I'll show what research I did, what did I try, and what problem(s) did I face while trying that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so using the

[`boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::async_receive_from()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive_from.html)

or

[`boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::receive_from()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/receive_from.html)

functions, which have the `endpoint_type & sender_endpoint` output parameter. The returned `endpoint` can be used to resolve the sender IP address.